# VBA Solver not Looping

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the solver on multiple columns (the exact number of columns being defined by the user). After looking at the questions here, I still can't find what's wrong with my code (I am pretty new to VBA). When I run it, it works fine for the first year but does not apply to the following years.

```vb
Dim wsFM_B3 As Worksheet
Set wsFM_B3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("xxxx_B3")

Dim wsCharts As Worksheet
Set wsCharts = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts")

Dim j As Integer

For j = 0 To Range("CC_Reduction_Years").Value
    SolverReset
    SolverAdd CellRef:=wsFM_B3.Range("E_Start").Offset(0, j), Relation:=3, FormulaText:=wsCharts.Range("Min_E")
    SolverAdd CellRef:=wsFM_B3.Range("Bank_Start").Offset(0, j), Relation:=3, FormulaText:=wsFM_B3.Range("Cash_B3")
    SolverOk SetCell:=wsFM_B3.Range("PoY_Start").Offset(0, j).Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=wsCharts.Range("CC_Base_Start").Offset(0, j).Address, Engine _
        :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve True
  Next j
End Sub
```

Here is what my `xxxx_B3` sheet looks like:

[image: Link to image]

On the "Charts" sheet there are only cells containing the target values for the first line, the constraints, and the number of years.

Comment: Could you show us some of your data? Does the code just stop or does it throw an error?

Comment: Sorry I can't, it's professional data. The code runs smoothly (no error message), it just does not apply after the first year.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the real data. Just give an example of your data structure, how your table "looks like".

Comment: I created a file but I can't find how to upload it to the discussion ... (newbie question)

Comment: I added an image of the file

Comment: In my experience Solver may do wrong things when actual `Range` objects are passed for `CellRef` and the sort. Add `.Address` after each one to make sure you pass addresses as strings.

Comment: Thank you for the edit BTW. I added `.Adress` after each one as you suggested but now my macro is not even working for the 1st year :s

Comment: That must be because you have multiple sheets involved, and `Address` does not include sheet name by default. Try using `Address(true, true, xlA1, true)`.

Comment: Thank you for the time you take to answer this. I tried what you suggested. The macro runs without trouble but does not change the numbers.

Comment: Then it probably does not find the solution. Open Solver manually after you run the marco and see what there is and whether it works.

Comment: Is the for loop working as expected? Depending on the value of `Range("CC_Reduction_Years").Value` the loop may be executed only once, which would explain working only for the first year. You may check this behaviour by debugging the code.