# How to use solver functions in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I made a macro for using the Excel solver quickly. But I don't know how to use the fomulatext function.

I want to change a constraint, when the row is changed.(when changed the row, I want to use its 34th column as the right-hand side).

Here's my code and the `solveradd CellRef:=Range(Cells(i + 1, 27), Cells(i + 1, 29)), relation:=1, formulatext:="Cells(i + 1, 34)"` is my wondering point (especially the `"Cells(i + 1, 34)"` part).

```
For i = 1 To nrepeat

SolverReset
solveradd CellRef:=Range(Cells(i + 1, 21), Cells(i + 1, 23)), relation:=3, formulatext:=0
solveradd CellRef:=Range(Cells(i + 1, 24), Cells(i + 1, 26)), relation:=1, formulatext:=0
solveradd CellRef:=Range(Cells(i + 1, 31), Cells(i + 1, 33)), relation:=3, formulatext:=0.0001
solveradd CellRef:=Range(Cells(i + 1, 27), Cells(i + 1, 29)), relation:=1, formulatext:="Cells(i + 1, 34)"
solveradd CellRef:=Cells(i + 1, 30), relation:=2, formulatext:=1
SolverOk SetCell:=Cells(i + 1, 34), MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:=Range(Cells(i + 1, 31), Cells(i + 1, 34)), Engine:=1
SolverSolve Userfinish:=True
```

Comment: I believe formulatext:= is equivalent to .formula= where you would put the calculation in... e.g. formulatext:= "="&Cells(i+1,34) would give the value in the cell at column 34, row i+1.

Comment: `FormulaText` accepts address of a cell with the formula. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/38630759/11683 and read the comments.