# How to set solver 'Value of:' to cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project where I have to calculate an end price based on a specific number with the price per item changing to equal said end price (see example image below).

[image]

However, I was curious if there is any possible way to run solver for multiple lines (like a formula) with the 'Value of' number being a cell reference instead of a static number.

Is this possible? Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: You can [automate running Solver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38630759/11683), but you can't use a formula for `Value of` within a run.

Answer (score 1):

Record a macro and take a look at the generated code.
Then it would have something like this within:

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$D$3", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=Y.Value, ByChange:="$D$2"
```

Try to change the `ValueOf=:` to `Range("F2")` and run it again.

Comment: hi, did this work for you? I get an error all the time " 'Error in model. Please verify all cells and constraints are valid"  I passed `ValueOf:=Range("I1")` and I also tried: `ValueOf:="I1"`

Comment: @Fierce82 See my answer below: the error goes away when you set a temporary variable to I1, and then set ValueOf to that temporary variable instead of directly to the cell.

Answer (score 0):

After recording a macro and using that code (see also [Vityata's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46406370/3673329)), replace the `ValueOf` element to a macro variable that you explicitly set/update *in the code*:

```
[... your thing that changes the value in Cell `$I$1` ...]

mytarget = Range("$I$1")

SolverOk SetCell:="$D$3", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=mytarget, ByChange:="$D$2"
```

You *must* set this temporary variable `mytarget` explicitly; directly assigning `ValueOf:=Range("$I$1")` in the `SolverOk` command would create a (sadly unintelligible) error message.

*Tentative explanation for the behavior (speculative): The solver expects the target value to be a fixed constant, i.e. remain unchanged during the solving procedure, but if you merely refer to a cell range, the solver could not automatically know that your value really does remain unchanged.*